# How can I script Preferences changes in an application?

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I want to use applescript to change a checkbox in the preferences box of Safari. I can open the preference window, but how to code the check box change?

Example: I'd like to toggle the check box for "Block pop-up windows" on tab "Security" of the preferences

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
   tell application "System Events"
      keystroke "," using command down
   end tell
   --some magic goes here
end tell
```

Answer (score 3):

Use UI Scripting:

http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/uiscripting/index.html

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896680/using-applescript-to-click-the-plus-button-in-a-preferences-window

[How to know the name of UI elements using Accessibility inspector (or any other tool)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/40436/how-to-know-the-name-of-ui-elements-using-accessibility-inspector-or-any-other)

Comment: Did the answer work for you?